# Selenium click() no longer functioning (w/ Eclipse/Maven/Firefox)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I just started working on some Selenium tests yesterday. I use Eclipse to run Maven builds in Java to test on Firefox. Just this morning, the tests were running fine. Then I went out for lunch and the click() function no longer works on my computer.

The way it's used is like this:

```
driver.findelement(by.xpath(".....")).click()
```

From what I can see, Selenium still works. The sendkeys function still automatically fills in fields, but no clicking occurs. Manually clicking buttons and boxes still works.

I thought I had accidentally changed something, so I deleted the tests and recloned the whole project, but still not functioning on my computer. The tests work fine on my mentor's computer. We're all stumped here.

Comment: Is it generating any exception ?

Comment: Do you have a `Maven` dependency on `firefox binary` and `geckodriver executables` in your `pom.xml`? Thanks

Comment: I am still not sure if `findelement` and `by` exists in Java binding you tagged. Can you confirm your `Selenium` binding please? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned the selenium test works at your mentors computer...

It's very important to know which WebDriver variant you are using when starting your tests. If the webdriver is using a real installed browser instance (e.g. FireFox) and your machine runs another browser version this could explain the situation.

I would suggest:

- first of all: check if you really got the same code base and there is
  really no change at all
- are you really using the same webdriver version?
- check webdriver target browser is same on both machines
- also try out HtmlUnit web driver on both machines
- when still problems:

  - refactor code, so click action is in one line
  - create a debug breakpoint at click()- location
  - call selenium tests in debug mode (on both machines) with a "real browser
    webdriver" - e.g. Firefox". Then do the "click" manually.
  - if it's still no react on the click there is something wrong with your
    browser

Comment: Restarting the computer fixes the problem